# How to change Jupyter installation path

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am try load GPT-J model, and he has 12gb size. And I want download/install her in HDD disk(name E). I change startup location of Jupiter to E disk (use c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = 'E:\Jupyter'), but jupyter load file in C:'user name'\ path. How I change download/install path of jupyter?

Answer (score 2):

You can open jupyter notebook on any directory you want. For example, if I want to open it in my E drive, I will got E drive and write `cmd` at top where the path is shown (below pic):

[image]

Then, the command prompt will open in that directory, you can just type `jupyter notebook` on that and it would open jupyter in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

Open a command prompt by clicking on "Start" -> "Run..." (or by pressing Windows+R on your keyboard).
Type "cmd" and press RETURN. This will open a command prompt window.
In the command prompt type the following commands:

```
E:
cd E:\Jupyter
jupyter
```

Leave the command prompt window open until you work with Jupyter. You can close it when you're done.

If the last command fails with an error, jupyter might not be added to your PATH. In this case try to open the Anaconda prompt from the start menu (in case you use Anaconda) and type the above commands in the Anaconda prompt.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Anaconda, you need to do one extra thing. Anaconda, by default, suppressed loading the config file.

To enable this file, edit the shortcut that launches Jupyter Notebook. You will find a target that looks like this:
`C:\...\python.exe C:\...\cwp.py C:\...\python.exe C:\...\jupyter-notebook-script.py "%USERPROFILE%/"`

Remove the `"%USERPROFILE%"`.